# Collective Noun: Is the possessive with "children" singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns

Which is preferred:

> Children will have their picture displayed.
>   OR
>   Children will have their pictures displayed.

The actually photographs *of children* not drawings

Comment: actually photographs of children not drawings

Comment: It is permissible to use singular-in-plural-context (eg 'Children, take your compasses in your right hand ...) as has been discussed here before. Then 'Children will have their picture displayed' disambiguates to one picture per child.

Comment: *If* the photo/s are **of** the children then for a single group photo:  *A photo of the children will be displayed*. More than one photo, the following is acceptable: **The children's photos will be displayed** Please specify if the photos (pictures) on display are more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Both work, different applications:

1. *Children will have their picture displayed.*

A single picture, covering everyone.

2. *Children will have their pictures displayed*

Multiple pictures, each of them covering everyone.

or

Multiple pictures, covering them individually and/or in groups.